# Combine relations javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two objects like this,

```
let tables=[{
    "KEY_ID": "T01",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 1",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
    "KEY_ID": "T02",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 2",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
    "KEY_ID": "T03",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 3",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}];
```

and

```
let orders = [{
        "KEY_ID": "T01",
        "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000004",
        "STATUS_DATA": 1
    }, {
        "KEY_ID": "T01",
        "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000005",
        "STATUS_DATA": 1
    }, {
        "KEY_ID": "T03",
        "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000018",
        "STATUS_DATA": 1
    }];
```

I want to combine orders to table objects like this
[Tabel Orders object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8ojv.png), How to do that? Can I use map function or something else? I know may be I must looping too much, but it's okay, don't worry about performance. Sorry I can't embed image or code for the results

Comment: You can make a lookup object (or a map) from the `orders_table` to lookup keys by unique values. From a very first look, I may guess that `KEY_ID` is unique. After that, simply iterate and build up orders, it should be one of the most efficient ways to approach the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let tables = [{
    "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
    "KEY_ID": "T01",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 1",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
 }, {
    "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
    "KEY_ID": "T02",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 2",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
 }, {
    "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
    "KEY_ID": "T03",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 3",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
 }, {
    "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
    "KEY_ID": "T04",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 4",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
 }, {
    "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
    "KEY_ID": "T05",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 5",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
 }];

let orders = [{ "KEY_ID": "T01", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000004", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T01", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000005", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T02", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000016", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T02", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000017", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T03", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000018", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }];

const table_orders = tables.map(t => {
  const table_order = orders.filter(o => o.KEY_ID === t.KEY_ID);
  table_order ? t.ORDERS = table_order : [];
  return t;
})

console.log(table_orders)
```

You can do as following

Comment: exactly as I expected

Answer (score 1):

You could make a lookup from the orders and fill the tables array through it, relying on `Array.reduce` and a plain `for..of` loop. This example assumes `key_id` is unique.

```js
let tables=[{
    "KEY_ID": "T01",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 1",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
    "KEY_ID": "T02",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 2",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
    "KEY_ID": "T03",
    "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 3",
    "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}], orders = [{
    "KEY_ID": "T01",
    "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000004",
    "STATUS_DATA": 1
}, {
    "KEY_ID": "T01",
    "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000005",
    "STATUS_DATA": 1
}, {
    "KEY_ID": "T03",
    "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000018",
    "STATUS_DATA": 1
}];

const ordersMap = orders.reduce((acc, next) => {
  if (!acc[next.KEY_ID]) acc[next.KEY_ID] = { orders: [] };
  acc[next.KEY_ID].orders.push(next);
  return acc;
}, {});

for (let table of tables) {
  table.orders = (ordersMap[table.KEY_ID] || {}).orders || [];
}
console.log(tables);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
let tables = [{
  "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
  "KEY_ID": "T01",
  "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 1",
  "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
  "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
  "KEY_ID": "T02",
  "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 2",
  "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
  "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
  "KEY_ID": "T03",
  "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 3",
  "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
  "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
  "KEY_ID": "T04",
  "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 4",
  "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}, {
  "COMPANY_ID": "FRKB",
  "KEY_ID": "T05",
  "KEY_NAME": "TABLE 5",
  "SITE_ID": "JKT"
}];

let orders = [{ "KEY_ID": "T01", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000004", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T01", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000005", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T02", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000016", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T02", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000017", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }, { "KEY_ID": "T03", "ORDER_ID": "BL/RK/D0000018", "STATUS_DATA": 1 }];

const ans = tables.map((obj) => {
  const newOrders = orders.filter((curr) => curr.KEY_ID === obj.KEY_ID)
  return {
  ...obj,
  orders: newOrders
}})

console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily and efficiently by creating a an object which has all the orders by the distinct `KEY_ID`s.

After building the object, you can iterate over your tables array and just set the `ORDERS` property by using the `KEY_ID`.

```
const ordersByKey = {}

orders.forEach(order => {
    if (!ordersByKey[order['KEY_ID']]) {
        ordersByKey[order['KEY_ID']] = []
    }

    ordersByKey[order['KEY_ID']].push(order)
});

tables.forEach(table => {
    table['ORDERS'] = ordersByKey[table['KEY_ID']] || [];
});

console.log(tables)
```